# Collapsible Tree Layout. Spread the branches evenly

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to replicate the below example with slight modifications. Rather than left to right orientation, i have changed the orientation to top to bottom. I am successful in altering the node sizes based on the size parameter in Json.

https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd

The issue i have is with branches not being evenly spread out. Please refer to the pic below. 
[image]

[image]

Please find attached the code for debugging purpose

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

div.tooltip {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
 height: 10px;
 padding: 8px;
 font: 10px sans-serif;
 background: #ffff99;
 border: solid 1px #aaa;
 border-radius: 8px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

</style>

<body bgcolor = '#F0FFF0'>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


<div align = "left">
<script>

var treeData =
{
  "name": "AON",
  "size": 4,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "India",
      "size": 4,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ARS",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "AAA",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "BBB",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "cCC",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "ddd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "eee",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "fff",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ggg",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hhh",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "www",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "qwww",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "sd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "tere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "rtr",
              "size": 4
            },
   {
              "name": "AAA",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "BBB",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "cCC",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "ddd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "eee",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "fff",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ggg",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hhh",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "www",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "qwww",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "sd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "tere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "rtr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wqw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hrfg",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Singapore",
      "size": 4,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "H&B",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "aasd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sdw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ghrr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "tyr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "eds",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hrtr",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "uyt",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewe",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yrt",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "uyu",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "erewr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "kyjy",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "GCP",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sdsf",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewt",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wetdse",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wetw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "qwsd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yrytw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewax",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "jttut",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "scscw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wetvd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewe",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "zc",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "zerete",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "sdaxa",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yeer",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sdaxa",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewretre",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ssdsrere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "asdsdere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "asdsdere",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "US",
      "size": 4,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Benfield",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "wes",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "dds",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sdsd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ryr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ty",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewe",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ggrt",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wetyr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hrfg",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hhf",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "ere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "vfgd",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "GCP",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "xx",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wqwq",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "xasa",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ooo",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ppp",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ll",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "lljk",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "kjjk",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "kui",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yu",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "li",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "uyu",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yuik",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yjm",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yu",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yikm",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yu",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "mmui",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yum",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "kyuyy",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "dffgy",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "erfdr",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  ;

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 30, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    //width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    //height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 width = 1000,
 height = 550;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + 400 + "," + margin.top + ")"); //580 is close to center

// Add tooltip div
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
 .attr("class", "tooltip")
 .style("opacity", 1e-6);
 
var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.cluster().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 160; });

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
 nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
     .attr("dy", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "2em" : "-1em";
     })
    .attr("dx", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "-1em" : "1em";
     })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

   
   
  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    //.attr('r', 10)
 .attr('r',function(d) { return d.data.size;  })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
 .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", function(d){mousemove(d);})
 .on("mouseout", mouseout);

 function mouseover() {
  div.transition()
  .duration(300)
  .style("opacity", 1);
 }

 function mousemove(d) {
  div
  .text(d.data.name)
  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
 }

 function mouseout() {
  div.transition()
  .duration(300)
  .style("opacity", 1e-6);
 }
 
  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.y0+200, y: source.x0+200}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.y+200, y: source.x+200}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.y;
    d.y0 = d.x;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.x} ${s.y}
            C ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${s.y},
              ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${d.y},
              ${d.x} ${d.y}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
</div>
<div align="right">
 <img src="aon.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:200px;height:100px;">
</div>

</body>
```

Kindly let me know where i need to modify to ensure that the links and text do not overlap into each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using d3.cluster instead of d3.tree will spread the intermediate branches out better (i.e. remove the clash between benfield and cp in your screenshot)

Then rotating the labels is the quickest fix to stop them overwriting each other, it's just a css rule:

```
.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

I also added a couple of dx/dy offsets to the d3 text attributes you set to make them line up better (rotating throws them off a bit depending on the anchor position)

That only gets you so far though, if you expand everything you see the bottom labels still overlap, you'd need to make it wider or restrict the number of branches that can open at the bottom level

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>

<body >

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


<div align = "left">
<script>

var treeData =
{
  "name": "AON",
  "size": 4,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "India",
      "size": 4,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ARS",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "AAA",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "BBB",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "cCC",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "ddd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "eee",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "fff",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ggg",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hhh",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "www",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "qwww",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "sd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "tere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "rtr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wqw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hrfg",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Singapore",
      "size": 4,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "H&B",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "aasd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sdw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ghrr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "tyr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "eds",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hrtr",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "uyt",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewe",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yrt",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "uyu",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "erewr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "kyjy",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "GCP",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sdsf",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewt",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wetdse",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wetw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "qwsd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yrytw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewax",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "jttut",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "scscw",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wetvd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewe",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "zc",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "zerete",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "sdaxa",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yeer",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sdaxa",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewretre",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ssdsrere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "asdsdere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "asdsdere",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "US",
      "size": 4,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Benfield",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "wes",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "dds",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "sdsd",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ryr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ty",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wewe",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ggrt",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wetyr",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hrfg",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wew",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "hhf",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "ere",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "vfgd",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "GCP",
          "size": 4,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "xx",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "wqwq",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "xasa",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ooo",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ppp",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "ll",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "lljk",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "kjjk",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "kui",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yu",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "li",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "uyu",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yuik",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yjm",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yu",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yikm",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yu",
              "size": 8
            },
            {
              "name": "mmui",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "yum",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "kyuyy",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "dffgy",
              "size": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "erfdr",
              "size": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  ;

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 30, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    //width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    //height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 width = 1000,
 height = 600;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + 580 + "," + margin.top + ")"); //580 is close to center

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.cluster().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 160; });

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
 nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
     .attr("dy", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "2em" : "-1em";
     })
    .attr("dx", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "-1em" : "1em";
     })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

   
   
  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    //.attr('r', 10)
 .attr('r',function(d) { return d.data.size;  })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.y0, y: source.x0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.y, y: source.x}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.y;
    d.y0 = d.x;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.x} ${s.y}
            C ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${s.y},
              ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${d.y},
              ${d.x} ${d.y}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
</div>
<div align="right">
 <img src="aon.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:200px;height:100px;">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you mgraham :) This is useful advice.

Comment: Sorry to bother u again.. Any chance you could point me to where i need to make changes so that the leaves are spread out as well.  I am re-editting the code on my question and attaching an extra pic that explains the issue

Comment: The leaves are as spread out as they're going to get given the width of the area they're displayed in. You'd need to increase the width i.e. change the variable. One thing you could do is change the separation function to grab a few pixels more https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#cluster_separation